# How can I remove the <p style="text-align:center"> (or left, right. The paragraph comes from database) using PHP?

Tags: php, html, css, tinymce

I have this html code that came from my database (I used TinyMCE to save the data)

```
<p style="text-align: center;">Come on grab your friends</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">Go to very distant lands</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">Jake the Dog and Finn the Human</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">The fun never ends</p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><strong>Adventure Time!</strong></p>
```

How can I remove those `<p></p>` tags considering that there can be other styles applied when using TinyMCE?

Comment: Do you mean you use PHP to read this file content? By the way, TinyMCE is a JS library. Do you want to process this in JS instead?

Comment: You can use                                                    $string = preg_replace('/<p[^>]*>(.*)<\/p[^>]*>/i', '$1', $string);

Comment: @Raptor I just use PHP, I'm not really into JS yet
@BuddhiEashwarage, it worked, but how can I put <br> to every line or every end of the `<p></p>` tags?

Comment: After Buddhi's line, add: `$string .= '<br />';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove HTML tags from a string you can use [**strip_tags()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php):

```
$str = '<p style="text-align: center;">Come and grab your friends</p>';

$str2 = strip_tags($str);

echo $str2; // "Come and grab your friends"
```

To keep certain tags, you can add an additional parameter:

```
$str = '<p style="text-align: center;"><strong>Adventure Time!</strong></p>';

$str2 = strip_tags($str, "<strong>"); // Preserve <strong> tags

echo $str2; // "<strong>Adventure Time!</strong>"
```

The second parameter is a string listing each tag you don't want stripped, for example:

```
$str2 = strip_tags($str, "<p><h1><h2>"); // Preserve <p>, <h1>, and <h2> tags
```

For more information, review the PHP documentation linked above.

Comment: this removes `<strong>` tag too.

Comment: It did remove the `<p></p>` tags, however, after removing it, I need to insert <br> to every line too. How can I do that?

Comment: After strip_tags(), concatenate a `<br>` --> `$str2 .= '<br>';`

Comment: It's better to use regex to remove `<p>` tags ONLY.

Comment: Uhm, actually, those 5 lines are stored in a single string.

Comment: @user3213531 Well...you could add the <br> before stripping tags... `str_replace("</p>", "</p><br>", $str);` then strip tags and preserve <br> ... that would work, but depending on what you're doing this may or may not be the best route... Not sure the extent of data variety you are dealing with, and what you are expecting/allowing...

Comment: `str_replace("</p>","</p><br>",$str);` solved the problem. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Although you mentioned that you don't use js, I would strongly encourage you to start using it. You will find it extremely useful in plenty of cases to just interfere to client-side rather than use just server-side procedures (as php does). So, just for the record, here is my suggested jQuery solution:

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- your head content here -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p style="text-align: center;">Come on grab your friends</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">Go to very distant lands</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">Jake the Dog and Finn the Human</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">The fun never ends</p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><strong>Adventure Time!</strong></p>
<div id="result"></div> <!-- here I have added an extra empty div to display the result -->

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p").each(function() {
        var value = $(this).text();
        $("#result").append(value+ "<br>");
        $(this).css("display", "none");
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Rykz9/1/

Hope you (and others)  find it useful... Happy coding!